# PS2010 - PSI - How can I retrieve a filtered list of projects from PSI?

Tags: project-server, ms-project-server-2010, psi

How can I retrieve a filtered list of projects via PSI ? I have tried via the Project web service and the ReadProjectStatus method, but there's no filtering feature in there.

There's also the ProjectGetProjectCenterProjectsForGridJson method in the internal PWA web service, which is actually undocumented, thus unusable...

Do you have any idea how to achieve this ? Is there a native way to do such filtering ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you wan't to get it filtered? The problem is, that there is only a pwa web service call to read the whole project list. If you need to filter this, you have to do it afterwards or read it directly from the database

Comment: Well, I could finally achieve what I wanted to after decompiling the PWA Web service DLL. I copied-pasted the code I needed, I reckon it's dirty, but it works...

Comment: Could you copy-paste that code here also? The code sugested by Sasidharan uses a method signature my 2010 PSI class does not have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter query.

```
private static Guid EnsureEnterpriseProject(string ProjectName)
    {

        SvcProject.ProjectDataSet ProjectDs = new SvcProject.ProjectDataSet();

        PSLibrary.Filter ProjectFilter = new Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Library.Filter();
        ProjectFilter.FilterTableName = ProjectDs.Project.TableName;
        ProjectFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(ProjectFilter.Project.TableName, ProjectFilter.Project.[Give column Name].ColumnName, PSLibrary.Filter.SortOrderTypeEnum.None));
        ProjectFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(ProjectFilter.Project.TableName, ProjectFilter.Project.[Give column Name].ColumnName, PSLibrary.Filter.SortOrderTypeEnum.None));
        ProjectFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(ProjectFilter.Project.TableName, ProjectFilter.Project.[Give column Name].ColumnName, PSLibrary.Filter.SortOrderTypeEnum.None));
        ProjectFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(ProjectFilter.Project.TableName, ProjectFilter.Project.[Give column Name].ColumnName, PSLibrary.Filter.SortOrderTypeEnum.None));

        PSLibrary.Filter.FieldOperator existingProject = new PSLibrary.Filter.FieldOperator(PSLibrary.Filter.FieldOperationType.Equal, ProjectDs.Project.[Give Column Name].ColumnName, ProjectName);
        projecteFilter.Criteria = existingProject;
        string filterXml = ProjectFilter.GetXml();
        ProjectDs = ServiceContext.Current.PSI.ProjectService.ReadProject(filterXml, false);
        if (ProjectDs.Project.Count >= 1)
        {
            //Get the desired value from the dataset.
        }
        return Valuegotfromdataset;
    }
```